# vaadin gui do not display on screen

Tags: java, vaadin

I have create vaadin demo to display an button on screen, but it display no thing, hope you help me in this problem,

My application :

```
public class StudentApplication extends Application {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public void init() {
    setTheme("mythemse");
    final Window w = new Window();
    setMainWindow(w);
    setContent(new LoginView());
  }

  public void setContent(LoginView loginView) {
    final Window window = new Window();
    window.setCaption("Login");
    window.setContent(loginView);
  }

}
```

My View:

```
public class LoginView extends Panel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private final CustomLayout loginLayout = new CustomLayout("login");

  public LoginView(){
    initalize();
    this.setSizeFull();
  }

  public void initalize() {
    Button loginButton = new Button("TEST");
    loginLayout.addComponent(loginButton,"testlogin");
    this.setContent(loginLayout);
  }
}
```

My html : webapp/VAADIN/themses/mythemses/layouts/login.html

```
<body class="login">
  <h1>
   <div location="testlogin" style="padding-left: 100px;"></div>
 </h1>    
</body>
```

And this is my WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Student</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>vaadin.terminal.gwt</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vaadin.servlet.VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>student.page.application.StudentApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>       
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadin.terminal.gwt</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>     
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My servlet:

```
public class VaadinApplicationServlet extends ApplicationServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file as well – if nothing is displayed on the page then Vaadin might be misconfigured in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Inside your setContent() method you create a new window which is not added anywhere, so it will never be shown.
You either need to set that as main window or add the new instance of LoginView to your main window.
i.e.
either this,

```
public class StudentApplication extends Application {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public void init() {
setTheme("mythemse");
//final Window w = new Window();
//setMainWindow(w);
setContent(new LoginView());
}
public void setContent(LoginView loginView) {
final Window window = new Window();
window.setCaption("Login");
window.setContent(loginView);
setMainWindow(window);
}
}
```

or this,

```
    public class StudentApplication extends Application {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void init() {
        setTheme("mythemse");
        final Window w = new Window();
        setMainWindow(w);
        setContent(new LoginView(),w);
        }
        public void setContent(LoginView loginView, Window window) {
//        final Window window = new Window();
        window.setCaption("Login");
        window.setContent(loginView);
        }
        }
```